# Android - How to finishes the all activities

Tags: android

My application have 10 activities. Every activity contains one button.if you click on that button then all activities will be finished(it means like Logout in gmail). Here i am using 2 steps. But it's not working.
1. Clear the stack using intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) for every activity calling.
2. this.finish() in button click listener.

How to implement it?

Comment: What for do you need 10 activities in your app?

Comment: each activity have some functionality. A1 for Login, A2 for welcome page,....like that

Comment: Do you need to back in previous activity when back button pressed?

Comment: @ naresh: Would you please see the related links on bottom right of this question.

Comment: No. I want to exit from the application if you click on the back button.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to be back when pressing the back button,you can call finish() right after calling the intent to go another activity.So current activity is finished.So you have to finish only the last activity where you are in.

If you call welcome form login like

```
startActivity(login.this,welcome.class);
finish();
```

And when you call finish() in welcome activity your application will finish() because it is the only activity as you already finished previous activity

Comment: How to finish remaining activities?

Comment: if you don't have to be back the activity from which you are going to another activity,you can finish them while you are leaving by calling the intent of another activity

Comment: I assumed that you don't need to be back as login->welcome and so

Comment: suppose  i am in welcome screen at this time i can  click on the back button then it will exit from the Application. is it clear?

Comment: this code can be put in the welcome screen back button listener. is it correct?

Comment: what comes first login or Welcome.It is for the first Activity.FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class

Comment: sorry it is not clear to you. First activity is Login here you can click on the back button then it will exit from the application. suppose we are in second activity called welcome(via Login activity) here you can click on the back button then it will exit form the application not come back to the login screen. now it is clear to you

Comment: put the code in the login.then if you click back in welcome program will finish

Comment: it's come back to login screen. it not exit from the application.

Comment: no way.if you put finish() in login after calling startActivity for welcome it won't

Answer (score 1):

use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP intent flag while calling each new activity.. so what it does is it clears all the top activities and starts this new activity...now if you'll close the current activity using finish()..it'll get closed and because of FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP all the others have been already closed...

it always work for me....check out the documentation for further reading..

Comment: this can be put before startActivity() or after startAcitvity()

Comment: when you assign a value to the intent..
suppose u have to start activity2...then you'll write
Intent i=new Intent(activity1.this,activity2.class)
now set the flag by writing

i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);

simple

Comment: i done same. but it's not work. it will just finish the current activity only and display the previous activity. not finish all the activities(it means not exit from the application).